# Internal Server Error ASP classic project

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, windows-server-2008

I developed a classic ASP application that allows a user to build their own PDF report. I have used the software by http://neeviapdf.com/PDFmerge/ to merge the pdf's. The application works great running locally in my VS2012. But when I publish the contents of the website to my remote windows 2008 server I get an internal server error when ever I try to build the report. 
I am lost and am not sure what the problem is. I have tried just about everything and am out of Ideas. The server is configured properly and I installed the mergepdf software on the server and gave the users using the application their permissions. And nothing has worked.

Here is my html markup I have gotten rid of most of the html code and just left the important stuff.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Build Your Own Report</title>
    <link href="css/mainel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) { 
        var viewportmeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="viewport"]'); 
        if (viewportmeta) { 
        viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0'; 
        jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
        document.body.addEventListener('gesturestart', function () { 
        viewportmeta.content = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.20, maximum-scale=1.0'; 
        }, false); 
        }); 
        } 
        } 
</script> 

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.url.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {


         var page = $('.report-tree .checkbox');
         var mainPage = $('.section-node .section-name');
         var allLink = $('.check-all');

         var pageNum;
         var Select_Section = $('.select-sec');
         var Clear_Section = $('.clear-sec');
         page.click(function () {
             pageNum = $(this).val();
             if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                 //console.log(pageNum);
             }
         });
         mainPage.click(function () {
             if ($(this).parent('div').parent('li').hasClass('expanded')) {
                 $(this).parent().parent('li').removeClass('expanded');
                 $(this).parent().parent('li').children('.inner-pages').slideUp(400);
             } else {
                 $(this).parent().parent('li').addClass('expanded');
                 $(this).parent().parent('li').children('.inner-pages').slideDown(400);
             }
         });
         allLink.click(function () {
             if (($(this).attr('id')) == 'select-all') {
                 page.attr('checked', 'checked');
                 $('input#report-submit.button').attr('src', 'img/build-my-report.jpg')
                 $('.section-node').parent('li').addClass('expanded');
                 $('.inner-pages').slideDown(400);
             } else {
                 page.attr('checked', '');
                 $('input#report-submit.button').attr('src', 'img/builder-btn.png')
                 $('.section-node').parent('li').removeClass('expanded');
                 $('.inner-pages').slideUp(400);
             }
             return false;
         });
         Select_Section.click(function () {
             $(this).parent('.select-links').parent('div').parent('li').children('.inner-pages').children('.report-subpages').children('li').children('.subpage-node').children('.checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
             $(this).parent('.select-links').parent('div').parent('li').children('.inner-pages').children('.report-subpages').children('li').children('.report-subpages').children('li').children('.subpage-node').children('.checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked');
             if ($(this).parent('.select-links').parent('div').parent('li').children('.inner-pages').children('.report-subpages').children('li').children('.subpage-node').children('.checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked')) {
                 $('input#report-submit.button').attr('src', 'img/build-my-report.jpg')
             }
             $(this).parent('.select-links').parent().parent('li').children('.inner-pages').slideDown(400);
             $(this).parent('.select-links').parent('div').parent('li').addClass('expanded');


             return false;
         });
         Clear_Section.click(function () {
             $(this).parent('.select-links').parent('div').parent('li').children('.inner-pages').children('.report-subpages').children('li').children('.subpage-node').children('.checkbox').attr('checked', '');
             $(this).parent('.select-links').parent('div').parent('li').children('.inner-pages').children('.report-subpages').children('li').children('.report-subpages').children('li').children('.subpage-node').children('.checkbox').attr('checked', '');
             if ($(this).parent('.select-links').parent('div').parent('li').children('.inner-pages').children('.report-subpages').children('li').children('.report-subpages').children('li').children('.subpage-node').children('.checkbox').attr('checked', '')) {
                 $('input#report-submit.button').attr('src', 'img/builder-btn.png')
             }
             $(this).parent('.select-links').parent().parent('li').children('.inner-pages').slideUp(400);
             $(this).parent('.select-links').parent('div').parent('li').removeClass('expanded');

             return false;
         });

         /*$('.checkbox').click(function () {
             if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                 alert('checked');
             else
                 alert('unchecked');
         });*/



         function setupProcessing(formData, jqForm, options) {


             var val = $('#report-builder').valid();
             if (val) {
                 $('#download-restart').hide();

                 $('#ajax-loader').show();

                 $('input#report-submit.button').attr('src', 'img/build-my-report.jpg').css({ 'opacity': '0.2', ' filter': 'alpha(opacity = 50)' });

             } else {
                 $('#make-a-selection').show();
             }
             return val;
         }
         function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
             $('#ajax-loader').hide();
             $('#download-report-link').attr('href', responseText);
             $('#download-restart').show();

             $('#report-submit').hide();

             $('#download-report-link').click(function () {
                 setTimeout("window.location = window.location", 100);
             });
         }

         var options = {
             //target:        '#output1',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
             beforeSubmit: setupProcessing,  // pre-submit callback 
             success: showResponse,  // post-submit callback 
             timeout: 30000,
             // other available options: 
             //url:       url         // override for form's 'action' attribute 
             //type:      "post",        // 'get' or 'post', override for form's 'method' attribute 
             //dataType:  null        // 'xml', 'script', or 'json' (expected server response type) 
             //clearForm: true,        // clear all form fields after successful submit 
             //resetForm: true,        // reset the form after successful submit 
             error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 alert("An error has occurred while generating your report, please try again later.\nThe error was: " + errorThrown);
                 $('#ajax-loader').hide();
                 $('#report-submit').show();
             }

         };

         // bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
         $('#report-builder').ajaxForm(options);

         $("#report-builder").validate({
             errorLabelContainer: "#make-a-selection",
             rules: {
                 "Page[]": "required"
             },
             messages: {
                 "Page[]": "Please choose at least one report to include."
             }
         });
         $('li.report-node-1 > div > input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
             if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                 $('input[type=checkbox][name=Page\[\]]', $(this).parents('.report-node-1')).attr('checked', false);
             }
         });
     });


</script>


</head>

<body>


                 <div class="page-content">
                     <div id="report-bulder">
                         <div id="make-a-selection" style="display:none;">
                         </div>


                <form name="Report_Builder" action="stjreport/mergepdf_a.asp" method="post" id="report-builder">
                    <input type="hidden" name="dowhat" value="merge" />
                    <ul class="report-tree">
                        <li class="report-node-1">
                            <div class="section-node">
                                <span class="section-name dark-green">
                                <input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="PageSec[]" value="1" id="page-1" />
                                    Letter from Daniel  J. Starks
                                <span class="arrow-1"></span>
                                </span>
                                <span class="select-links">
                                    <a href="#select-section" class="select-sec">Select Section</a> | <a href="#clear-section" class="clear-sec" >Clear Section</a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inner-pages">
                                <ul class="report-subpages">
                                    <li><div class="subpage-node">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Page[]" value="letter-to-our-shareholder.pdf" id="letter-1" />
                                        <label for="letter-1" class="label-1">Letter from Daniel  J. Starks</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="report-node-1">
                            <div class="section-node">
                                <span class="section-name light-green">
                                    <input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="PageSec[]" value="1" id="Hidden1" />Embrace the Future<span class="arrow-2"></span></span>
                                        <span class="select-links"><a href="#select-section" class="select-sec">Select Section</a> | <a class="clear-sec" href="#clear-section">Clear Section</a>
                                        </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="inner-pages">
                                <ul class="report-subpages">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="subpage-node"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Page[]" value="Infinity-Full-Annual-Report-2.pdf" id="embrace-1" />
                                            <label for="embrace-1" class="label-2">Products</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="subpage-node"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Page[]" value="Infinity-Full-Annual-Report-3.pdf" id="embrace-2" />
                                            <label for="embrace-2" class="label-2">Service</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="subpage-node">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Page[]" value="Infinity-Full-Annual-Report-4.pdf" id="embrace-3" />
                                            <label for="embrace-3" class="label-2">Technology</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="subpage-node">
                                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Page[]" value="Infinity-Full-Annual-Report-5.pdf" id="embracee-4" />
                                            <label for="embrace-4" class="label-2">Marketing</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="report-node-1"><div class="section-node"><span class="section-name purple">
                            <input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="PageSec[]" value="10" id="page-10" />Case Study<span class="arrow-3"></span></span>
                            <span class="select-links"><a href="#select-section" class="select-sec">Select Section</a> | <a class="clear-sec" href="#clear-section">Clear Section</a></span></div>
                            <div class="inner-pages">
                                <ul class="report-subpages">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="subpage-node"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Page[]" value="Infinity-Full-Annual-Report-6.pdf" id="case-1" />
                                            <label for="case-1" class="label-3">Florida Case Study</label></div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="subpage-node"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Page[]" value="Infinity-Full-Annual-Report-7.pdf" id="case-2" />
                                            <label for="case-2" class="label-3">California Case Study</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="report-node-1"><div class="section-node">
                            <span class="section-name red"><input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="PageSec[]" value="11" id="page-11" />Corporate Social Responsibility<span class="arrow-4"></span>
                            </span>
                            <span class="select-links"><a href="#select-section" class="select-sec">Select Section</a> | <a class="clear-sec" href="#clear-section">Clear Section</a></span></div>
                            <div class="inner-pages">
                                <ul class="report-subpages">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="subpage-node"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Page[]" value="Infinity-Full-Annual-Report-11.pdf" id="social-1" />
                                             <label for="social-1" class="label-4">Corporate Social Responsibility</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="report-node-1">
                            <div class="section-node"><span class="section-name yellow"><input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="PageSec[]" value="12" id="page-12" />Corporate Information <span class="arrow-5"></span></span><span class="select-links"><a href="#select-section" class="select-sec">Select Section</a> | <a class="clear-sec" href="#clear-section">Clear Section</a></span></div>
                            <div class="inner-pages">
                                <ul class="report-subpages">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="subpage-node"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Page[]" value="Infinity-Full-Annual-Report-12.pdf" id="corporate-information-1" /> 
                                            <label for="corporate-information-1" class="label-5">Corporate Information</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="report-node-1"><div class="section-node">
                            <span class="section-name purple"><input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="PageSec[]" value="13" id="page-13" />Financial Highlights<span class="arrow-3"></span></span><span class="select-links"><a href="#select-section" class="select-sec">Select Section</a> | <a class="clear-sec" href="#clear-section">Clear Section</a></span></div>
                            <div class="inner-pages">
                                <ul class="report-subpages">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="subpage-node"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="Page[]" value="Infinity-Full-Annual-Report-13.pdf" id="financial-1" /> 
                                            <label for="financial-1" class="label-3">Financial Highlights</label>
                                        </div> 
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="check-controls">
                         <div class="controls-holder">
                             <a href="#select-all" class="check-all" id="select-all">Select all</a> | <a href="#clear-all" class="check-all" id="clear-all">Clear all</a>
                         </div>
                     </div><!-- end .check-controls -->
                    <div class="builder-buttons">
                        <div>
                            <input type="image" name="Submit" class="button" id="report-submit" src="img/builder-btn.png" />
                            <div id="ajax-loader"  style="display:none;margin-top:8px; text-align:right;"><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
                            <div id="download-restart" style="display:none;">
                                <div class="button-block">
                                    <!--a id="download-report-link" target="_blank" href="#"><img src="../i/download_button.gif" alt="Download Report" width="120" height="24" border="0" /></a-->
                                    <a id="download-report-link" target="_blank" href="#" style="font-weight: bold;font-size:14px;margin:15px 0 15px 0;"></a>
                                </div><!-- end .button-block-->
                                <div class="button-block">
                                    <!--a id="restart-link" href=""><img src="../i/new_report_button.gif" alt="Start New Report" width="120" height="24" border="0" /></a-->
                                </div><!-- end .button-block-->
                            </div><!-- end #download-restart -->
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end #bulder-builder -->
                </form><!-- end #report-builder -->
                     </div><!-- end #report builder -->
                 </div><!-- end .page-content-->
             </div><!-- end #contright -->
         </div><!--end .wrapper .floatwrapper-->
     </div><!--end .buildreportmain-->


**When the form is submitted I call the following server side scripts. This is the code the does all the back end processing in the order that they are called**



    **mergepdf_a.pdf**
    <!--#include file="_mergepdf.asp"-->/stjreport/temp/<%=fileName %>.pdf

    **_mergepdf.asp**
    <%
        Response.Buffer = True
        Response.ExpiresAbsolute = Now() - 1
        Response.Expires = 0
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
    %>
    <!--#include file="includes/includes.inc"-->
    <%
        set fso = server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set NVmerge = CreateObject("Neevia.PDFmerge")

        action = LCase(trim(request("dowhat")))  
        cleanitup(300)

        select case action
            case "merge"
                inPath = ""

                ' more efficient loop?
                For Each item In Request.Form("Page[]")
                    if fso.fileExists(pdf_path &"/"& trim(item)) then inPath = inPath & pdf_path & "/" & trim(item) & "+"
                Next

    '            for m=1 to 50
    '                for n=1 to 50
    '                    if len(trim(request("chb_"&m&"_"&n))) > 0 then  
    '                        if fso.fileExists(pdf_path &"/"& trim(request("chb_"&m&"_"&n))) then inPath = inPath & pdf_path & "/" & trim(request("chb_"&m&"_"&n)) & "+"
    '                    end if
    '                next
    '            next
                if len(trim(inPath)) > 0 then 
                    inPath = left(inPath,len(inPath)-1)
                    fileName = replace(replace(replace(now(),"/",""),":","")," ","")
                    fileName = fileName & makeRandomString(2)
                    outPath = tmp_Path & "/" & fileName & ".pdf"
                    success = NVMerge.MergePDF(inPath,outPath)
    'response.write "inpath: " & inpath & "<br>"
    'response.write "outpath: " & outpath & "<br>"               
    'response.write "s: " & success & "<br>"
    'response.flush               
                end if
        end select
    %>


    **includes.inc**

    <%
        thisPage = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
        thisPage = Right(thisPageName,Len(thisPage) - InStrRev(thisPage,"/"))

        session.timeout = 5
        webDir = "/stjreport"
        pdf_path = server.MapPath("/") & webDir & "/pdfs"
        tmp_path = server.MapPath("/") & webDir & "/temp"

        Function RoundUp(n)
            roundUp = Int(n) - CBool(CDbl(n) <> CLng(n))
        End Function

        Sub cleanItUp(tt) 
            set incFS = server.createobject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
            set incFO = incFS.GetFolder(tmp_path)
            for each incF in incFO.files
                'if instr(1,incF.name,".pdf",1) > 0 then
                    set tmpF = incFS.GetFile(incF)
                    if DateDiff("s",tmpF.DateCreated,now) > tt then incFS.deleteFile(tmpF)
                'end if
            next
            set incFO = nothing
            set incFS = nothing
        End Sub

        Function makeRandomString(incLength)
            makeRandomString = ""
            seedStr = "1,N,O,P,Q,3,W,X,Y,Z,$,4,0,A,B,C,D,E,F,8,G,H,I,J,5,6,7,9,K,L,M,R,2,S,U,V,T,"
            rndAry = Split(seedStr,",")
            rndName = ""    
            For inc = 1 to incLength
                Randomize
                iRandom = Int( UBound( rndAry ) * Rnd )
                rndName = rndName & rndAry( iRandom )
            next
            makeRandomString = rndName
        End Function    

        Sub displayMessage  (incMsg,incReturnUrl)
            if Len(incMsg) > 0 then
                Response.write("<br /><br /><p style='text-align:center; font-family:arial; font_size:larger;'>" & incMsg & "</p>")
    %>
    <script language="javascript">
                alert("<%=Replace(Replace(incMsg,"<br />","\n"),"<br>","\n")%>");
    <%
                if Len(incReturnUrl) > 0 then
    %>                      
                    top.location.href = "<%=incReturnUrl%>";
    <%
                else
    %>
                    top.history.go(-1);
    <%
                end if
    %>                                                  
    </script>
    <%
                Response.end()
            end if                      
        End Sub             

        Function isPermittedFile(incFileType,incFile)   
            incFile = replace(incFile, "\", "/")
            if inStr(incFile,"/") > 0 then
                incAry = split(incFile,"/")
                incFile = incAry(uBound(incFile)-1)
            end if
            if inStr(incFile,".") = 0 then call (displayMessage("Image file: " & incFile & " sounds not to be a recognized image format",""))
            incFileAry = split(incFile,".")
            incExt = incFileAry(1)

            Select Case LCase(incFileType)
                Case "image"
                    incAllowedStr = ",gif,png,jpg,jpeg,bmp,tiff,"
                Case "document"
                    'incAllowedStr = ",pdf,doc,docx,txt,rtf,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,"
                    incAllowedStr = ",pdf,"
            End Select
            isPermittedFile = False
            if inStr(1,incAllowedStr,","& LCase(incExt) &",",1) > 0 then isPermittedFile = True
        End Function

    %>

Again it works locally but for some reason it breaks on the live server. Any help would be great.
```

Comment: Try setting up server for IIS to send errors to client, and if using Internet Explorer, change it's Internet Options/Advanced/Show Friendly HTTP error messages to "off". Or capture and log the error through code. Showing the exact error would help a lot.

Comment: Thank you I will try that now and see what I get

Comment: This is the error message i get **An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.**  @G.Stoynev

Comment: This is still a generic message and not the real 500 server error. Depending on your configuration (production vs. lab server; ability to debug; running browser locally or remotely) you have different avenues to see the actual error. In any case, if logging is enabled, you can check IIS logs for it. But your best option is to be able to reproduce the error on a machine on which you can use a debugger to step into the server-side code.

Comment: Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a004c'

Path not found

/build-your-own-report/stjreport/includes/includes.inc, line 16 @G.Stoynev

Comment: it seems that my path to the temps folder is not right... Line 16 in the includes.inc is the following. **set incFO = incFS.GetFolder(tmp_path)** and it is being set here **tmp_path = server.MapPath("/") & webDir & "/temp"** @G.Stoynev

Answer (score 0):

*Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a004c' Path not found /build-your-own-report/stjreport/includes/includes.inc, line 16*

How are you linking to your files? Do you have parent paths enabled to allow links across folders. Either way, included files should never start with a slash (/) in Classic ASP.

For links within a same folder use "build-your-own-report/etc..." or out and into another folder like "../build-your-own-report/etc"